# ReadFields() in TextFieldParser throwing exception

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, csv, textfieldparser

I have a bunch of csv files in a folder. Here is a sample:

```
Item    Value
Row1    Val1
Row2    Val2
Row3    Val3
Row4    Val4"
Row5    Val5
```

I had written a code to plot a chart based on the information available in all the csv file in that folder. Here is my button click event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles generatePlot.Click

        Dim dirs As FileInfo() = GetFilesInDirectory("*.csv", True) 'Get all the csv file from result folder in descending order (creation date)
        Dim diNext As FileInfo

        Try
            For Each diNext In dirs.Reverse
                Using MyReader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(diNext.FullName)
                    MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                    MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
                    Dim currentRow As String()
                    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                        processRow(diNext, currentRow)
                    End While
                End Using
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
        End Try

        'Save chart as an image
        Chart1.SaveImage(imageSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

    End Sub
```

If you look at my sample csv, **Row4 has a value of Val4"**. Note the double quote in it. And, I am getting an exception in my code at **currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()** which says **Line 5 cannot be parsed using the current delimiter**. I know that the reason is because of the presence of double quote. Since this is a string array, I thought that I need to create a function to process each item in the array and trim out the double quote. But, I can't do it as the exception is thrown even before I can process the string array.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Hari

Comment: A lone double-quote (double QUOTE, not double CODE) isn't really valid in a properly-formatted CSV file. Double-quotes are used to wrap field values that do or might contain field or record delimiters so any literal double-quote in the data should be escaped, which is done by preceding it with another double-quote. That's exactly the same as you do in VB `String` literals. As an example, if you want the text `He said "Hello" to me` then your actual data should be `He said ""Hello"" to me`.

Comment: What that means is that, if you want to read the actual data you have, you'll have to write custom code to do so because the `TextFieldParser` expects the data it reads to follow the rules.

Comment: I understand the concept of preceding a double quote with another double quote. But, my limitation is the data I am processing has a single double Quote at some values

Comment: Then you have two choices. You can either preprocess the data and replace any lone double-quotes with pairs of double-quotes or you can not use a `TextFieldParser` and parse the data yourself. If you know that the field values will not contain any commas or line breaks then the latter may be the easier option. In that case you can just call `File.ReadLines` and then call `Split` on each line.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set `MyReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error when using .NET Framework 4.7.1 in VS2017 on Windows 10. What enviroment are you using?

Comment: @Andrew Morton, I am using .NET Framework 4 Client Profile in VS2010 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [StreamReader can be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-text-from-files-with-a-streamreader) to read text files, just look at the example below to achieve your needs:

Note that the `MemoryStream` and the `Writer` are not needed for you, just the `Reader`.

```
Public Sub ReadTest()
    Using MemoryStream As New IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim Writer As New IO.StreamWriter(MemoryStream) 'Writing on a memory stream to emulate a File
        Writer.WriteLine("Item,Value")
        Writer.WriteLine("Row1,Val1")
        Writer.WriteLine("Row2,Val2")
        Writer.WriteLine("Row3,Val3")
        Writer.WriteLine("Row4,Val4""")
        Writer.WriteLine("Row5,Val5")

        Writer.Flush()
        MemoryStream.Position = 0 'Reseting the MemoryStream to Begin Reading

        Dim Reader As New IO.StreamReader(MemoryStream) 'Reading from the Memory but can be changed into the File Path
        While Not Reader.EndOfStream
            Dim Line As String = Reader.ReadLine
            Dim Values() = Line.Split(",")
            'Values(0) will contain the First Item
            'Values(1) will contain the second Item

            Values(1).Replace("""", "") 'Remove the quote from the value string

        End While

    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion given by @jmcilhinney and @AugustoQ.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles generatePlot.Click

        Dim dirs As FileInfo() = GetFilesInDirectory("*.csv", True) 'Get all the csv file from result folder in descending order (creation date)
        Dim diNext As FileInfo
        Dim currentRow As String()
        Try
            For Each diNext In dirs.Reverse
                For Each rawRows As String In File.ReadLines(diNext.FullName)
                    currentRow = processRawRow(rawRows)
                    processRow(diNext, currentRow)
                Next
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
        End Try

        'Save chart as an image
        Chart1.SaveImage(imageSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

    End Sub
```

I had replaced the TextFieldParser completely and used this function:

```
Private Function processRawRow(ByVal rawRows As String) As String()

        rawRows = rawRows.Replace("""", "").Trim()
        Dim processedList = rawRows.Split(",")
        Return processedList

    End Function
```

And it works perfectly. Thanks everyone...

Hari